# Coding Challenge: Return The Smaller String

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, strings, complexity

A coding challenge in which we are to write a function that compares two strings and returns the one that is smaller. The comparison is both lexicographical and numerical, depending on the content of the strings as explained below and in the comments of the code.

Both strings may contain any characters. Consecutive numbers in the string are considered a single number. If during the search the character of only one string is a number, then that string is returned as numbers are lexicographically smaller than letters.

If during the search the characters of both strings are numbers, then `parseInt(strX.slice(i))` checks if there are more consecutive digits in each string and returns the string whose number is numerically smaller.

Examples:

input: `"a"`, `"b"`
expected output: `"a"` since `"a"` comes before `"b"` alphabetically

input: `"a1"`, `"a2"`
expected output: `"a1"` since 1 comes before 2

input: `"a10"`, `"a2"`
expected output: `"a2"` since 2 comes before 10

Here is the code:

```
const smallestString = (str1, str2) => {
    // we only need to iterate through the shortest string
    const len = str1.length < str2.length ? str1.length : str2.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // check if both letters are strings
        if (str1[i].toUpperCase() !== str1[i].toLowerCase() && str2[i].toUpperCase() !== str2[i].toLowerCase()) {
            if (str1[i] === str2[i]) { // if both letters are the same, continue
                continue;
            } else {
                return str1[i] < str2[i] ? str1 : str2; // otherwise return the string with the 'smaller' char at that index
            }
        } else if (!isNaN(str1[i] || !isNaN(str2[i]))) { // check if either char is a number
            if (!isNaN(str1[i]) && !isNaN(str2[i])) { // if both chars are numbers, return str with numerically smaller number
              return parseInt(str1.slice(i)) < parseInt(str2.slice(i)) ? str1 : str2;
            }
        } else {
            return str1[i] < str2[i] ? str1 : str1;
        }
    }
    return str1; // if we get here then both strings are equal and either can be returned
}

console.log(smallestString('a10', 'a2')); // returns 'a2'
```

I am seeking any and all feedback about cleaning up the code and possibly improving the algorithm's current time complexity of O(n).

Comment: Can we assume ANSI encoding of the strings, or can they include extended Unicode characters?

Comment: At this point I would only assume ANSI.

Comment: Since you may have to compare every character, you can't get below $O(n)\$.

Comment: I was pretty sure that the time complexity of this problem cannot be less than O(n), however, I would still like feedback for refactoring.

Comment: What is the expected output of `('a10', 'ab')`?

Comment: @vnp 'a10', since in such a case since a string with a number in it will be lexicographically smaller than a string with no numbers in it. If the current index of both strings is a number, then `parseInt(strX.slice(i))` checks if there are more consecutive digits in the string and returns the string whose number is numerically smaller.

Comment: You have to specify it in the problem statement. Otherwise it is unclear if the code works _correctly_.

Comment: @vnp Please see edits above. The problem should now be clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if (!isNaN(str1[i]) && !isNaN(str2[i])) { // if both chars are numbers, return str with numerically smaller number
          return parseInt(str1.slice(i)) < parseInt(str2.slice(i)) ? str1 : str2;
        }
```

seems like a bug. In case the numbers compare equal the code blindly returns the first string. Consider `(a10c, a10b)`.

---

```
return str1; // if we get here then both strings are equal and either can be returned
```

seems like another bug. At this point we only know that the strings are equal *up to the length of the shortest one*, and the shortest one should be returned. Which one is shortest is not tested here.

---

The overall logic looks overcomplicated. Consider testing for numbers first; that would eliminate the need for a confusing `toUpper/toLower` mess, and the special case of special characters.

Comment: Well I didn't see the bug, but I fixed it now. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should I edit the post since this is Code Review?

Comment: @SeanValdivia No. Post a follow-up question.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Will the content of this follow-up question have the same code as above, but fixed?